# jQueryUI Sortable | Drag elements among different parents

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it actually possible?

Here is my simplified [mockup](http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/1284/epo6.png). Green rows can have more than one cell and must be draggable/sortable. They can be dragged anywhere from top to bottom. Red cells always stay in place because they're dates.

Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ruHPY/2/):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>May 01</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>May 02</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>May 02</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 1) You don't have any scripting in your fiddle.
2) Wouldn't `$('td td:first child').draggable();` do the trick? **Either way**, it's definitely possible. The widget allows you to define what's draggable and what it can be dropped on.

Comment: There's no scripting because I don't know what to write there... Just `$("tbody").sortable();` won't help because my trs are in different parents. Draggable won't work because it serves different purpose. I need my rows to be sortable.

Comment: If you don't even make an attempt, you're probably not going to get much help, sorry.

Comment: Ok, here's my attempt - http://jsfiddle.net/ruHPY/3/
It does what I wanted it to, I just had to use 'connectWith' option for sortable. However there's a problem - if there's only one row and I drag it away than I can't drag anything in that place. Obviously it happens because there are no tds in that table and thus no height so no place to drag to. How do I work that around? Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah - actually add the <tbody> tags in the table and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/ruHPY/4/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>May 01</td>
        <td class="mt3">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>1 Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>May 02</td>
        <td class="mt3">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>2 Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3 Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>May 02</td>
        <td class="mt3">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>4 Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>6 Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
    $(".mt3 tbody").sortable({
            connectWith: ".mt3 tbody",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
            }
        });
    $("td").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: No, it's not fine. It's the same problem as I said - try to drag row #1 somewhere and then try to drag it back to "May 01". It won't go there because tbody is empty and has no height. And you cannot set height for tbody. Any ideas?